# Passport.js : Are UID unique?

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js, facebook-login

I've a Nodejs app and I use Passeport to let my users connect throught Facebook or Google via Oauth. I'm storing basic data after connection such as : uid, firstname etc.

How can I be assured that the uid I'm receiving will be always unique for a given user ? I mean, data is coming either from Facebook or Google, so why couldn't I face a nasty duplicate uid for different users someday ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UID is unique only within the scope of that single provider’s list of users.

[This article](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/) suggests you combine the provider’s name plus the UID to get a unique value.

> Combination of provider’s name and uID will uniquely identify user inside our app.

I would use the provider’s domain name such as “google.com” or “com.google”.

Answer (score 4):

The id you are getting via OAuth is unique when you are using either Facebook or Google. But if you want to use both then I would suggest make your **dbSchema** (if you are using mongoose) like this -

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    username: String,
    password: String
  },
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String
  },
  google: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String
  }
});
```